# How do i input this table in a text file into C?

Tags: c, file-io

my text file goes something like this:

> 0 000 fff1
>
> 0 121 afaada4
>
> 0 000 mm1m1

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
if (fi) {
    while(fscanf(fi,"%d" "%d" "%s",&sigs1,&sigs2,&sigs3)!=EOF);  
    printf("%d %d %s",sigs1,sigs2,sigs3);   
    fclose(fi);  
}
```

Comment: `&sigs3` ==> `sigs3`, and do your realise that the `;` at the end of the `while` statement creates an empty code block, and the following code is executed just once?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] and describe the current behaviour of your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sigs1, sigs2;
    char * sigs3;
    FILE *fi;
    fi = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (fi) {
        while(fscanf(fi,"%d " "%d"  "%s ",&sigs1,&sigs2,sigs3)!=EOF)
            printf("%d %03d %s\n",sigs1,sigs2,sigs3);
        fclose(fi);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
0 000 fff1
0 121 afaada4
0 000 mm1m1
```

Comment: Windows gives .exe stopped working.

Comment: `char * sigs3;` --> `char sigs3[32];` or something like this.